# Electron's setTimeout vs. window.setTimeout

Tags: node.js, electron, timeout

In an Electron app, there are two ways to set a timeout. One is NodeJS's `setTimeout` function, which returns a `NodeJS.Timeout` object. The other is `window.setTimeout` which returns a `number`. Is there any reason to choose one over the other in the renderer process?

Comment: can you actually choose between the two? My understanding was that in the main process, you will always use Node's, but in a renderer, you'd use the regular setTimeout. Maybe that's not true...

Comment: though maybe the typings will suggest that NodeJS.Timeout is possible to do in the renderer. Not sure if that will actually work though at runtime